# Dashboard/Reports Can Access without giving access to user

Tags: permissions, dashboard, sales-cloud, custom-reports

Currently doing some Dashboard/Reports. just found a weird problem. I've created a dashboard/Report which is under a created folder (System Administrator Access). In that folder I did not give any share access to any role or anyone. But when I tried to access the dashboard using a different user (Login As). That User can see or access my created dashboard/report. Also the folder where its currently saved. All of this is under a Sandbox Environment. Is this a Sandbox thing only? or Am i doing something wrong? User has no Manage Permission on Reports/Dashboard

[image]

Comment: Hi, Report/Dashboard can be accessed only if the folders are shared to those users. The permission you have highlighted, not only through profiles but also via permission set it can be granted. And if those folders are public folders then user can access those reports and those users will not be listed in sharing section on those folders.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar... how do i know if the folder i created is a public folder?.
I didnt gave any access to the folder i've created.

Comment: If you have created those folders then it is accessible only by you and to users with administrative permissions, until you share it. In your case if the user is not an admin, pls check if any permission set is assigned to that user be able to access all reports and dashboards.